# Asynchronous forEach function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach

I'm trying to build an asynchronous `forEach` function, but unfortunately it returns the value `undefined` instead of the content of the array for which I had hoped for. What am I doing wrong?

```
function asyncforEach(array, cb) {
    array.forEach(function(){
        setTimeout(cb, 0);
    });
}

asyncforEach([1,2,3,4], function(i) {
    console.log(i)
});
```

Comment: Why do you expect anything from the array to be logged? `i` is `undefined` since you’re not passing any argument to `cb`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the variable (`value`) to the callback, in [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

```js
function asyncforEach(array, cb) {
  array.forEach(function(value){ // value: The current array entry
    setTimeout(cb, 0, value);    // Pass it to the callback when setTimeout invokes it.
  });
}
    
asyncforEach([1,2,3,4], function(i) {
  console.log(i)
});
```

Any parameters passed to `setTimeout` after the `function` and `delay` parameters, are passed to the callback:

```
var timeoutID = scope.setTimeout(function[, delay, param1, param2, ...]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed to get the `item` in the `forEach` function parameter and pass the item into the `setTimeout`, Also call the `cb` function with passed array item into it. This will force the `cb` function to be called inside the arrow function, when the time will be out.

```js
function asyncforEach(array, cb) {
    array.forEach(function(i) {
        //-----------------^---
        setTimeout( () => cb(i), 0);
        //----------^^^^^^^^^^^----
    });
}

asyncforEach([1,2,3,4], function(i) {
    console.log(i)
});
```

Comment: You don't need to add the arrow function there.

Comment: For that downvote? If yes that is no purpose downvote, I have my approach another one has it's approach, meanwhile this also works

Comment: Somebody was downvoted, I don't say it you. If it is downvoted it means that something is wrong, but not